# Broken Package, Unable to install anything.!

Tags: apt, software-installation

I know there is so many solution for this but I tried all those none of them are working.

When I tried `apt-get install -f` ...

```
siddharth@Sid-HP-dv6:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for siddharth: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgcc1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgcc1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 130 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb containing libgcc1:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.8.1-10ubuntu9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package name
```

I am unable to install anything, There is a red error icon came on status bar..showing An error occurred, please run package mangaer......

Now please guide me, what should I do?????????????

Here is output when I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: debconf-i18n but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also tried

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

It helped me for 5 mins only then problem came again...

Comment: Means `debconf` is not installed on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
 debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
```

IMO, dpkg won't able to get the debconf version.Is that, debconf package installed on your system? Reinstalling the `debconf` package will correct this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```